# Is it possible to stop a lifecycle hook in angular2?

Tags: angular

I would like to stop a Lifecycle Hook in angular2 when a variable gets a value of `true`. Is it possible?

I didn't find anything anywhere, but I think it would be very cool to do so.

Comment: What lifecycle hook and what do you mean with "stop"?

Comment: When you ask a value to firebase in a lifecycle, like if a user is logged, it returns a lot of of times false and another lot times true. I would like to stop it whenever the value turns to true.

Comment: Stop what? What behavior do you expect when "stop" happens? You can use router guards to prevent navigation to a specific route https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Comment: Stop this: `false false false false (loggedin) true true true true` I want it to be `false false false false (loggedin) true`

Comment: we're not mind readers. add "firebase" to your tags and say which event you're talking about at least.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.newValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentValue));
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did is to declare a flag boolean variable outside the lifecycle. Then I changed it whenever my `isLoggedIn()` is `true` and do something only if the flag variable is `true`.

I could not stop the lifecycle, but I simulated it.